# MudBlazor scrollable content with pinned ToolBar

Tags: html, css, flexbox, c#-3.0, mudblazor

I want achieve the following result using the MudBlazor library.

1. The (A) element i want to be a MudToolBar with secondary color pinned in the top of the Container
2. The (C) element i want it to be a MudToolBar again stuck in the bottom of the Container
3. The (B) element i want it to be a Scrollable container with whatever i put inside. When i scroll it, the elements A && C MUST not scroll along with the content.

All of that is diplayed inside a Drawer's main content

```
<MudMainContent>
        <MudPaper Class="d-flex flex-grow-1 gap-4" Elevation="0">
            <MudLayout>
                // Here i will write the whole component
            </MudLayout>
        </MudPaper>
    </MudMainContent>
```

Up to now i have done the following

```
<div class="d-flex flex-grow-1 flex-row">
    <MudPaper Elevation="25" Class="flex-grow-1">
        <MudToolBar> 
            A-Element
        </MudToolBar>


   <div class="d-flex flex-column" style="max-height:100vh;min-height:100vh; overflow:scroll;">
            // Here there will be a ForEach loop creating elements B-Element
    </div>
    <MudPaper Elevation="25" Class="d-flex flex-row px-2 mx-4" Style="">
         C-Element
    </MudPaper>
    </MudPaper>
</div>
```

How can i do that??

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```html
<div class="d-flex flex-column" style="height:100vh; overflow-x:auto;">
            // Here there will be a ForEach loop creating elements B-Element
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

with the same Condition
I found this solution useful:

```
<MudPaper Class="d-flex flex-column overflow-x-auto " Height="100vh">
    Your Content
</MudPaper>
```

for more information you can read these:

1. [Enable Flexbox in MudBlazor](https://mudblazor.com/utilities/enable-flex)
2. [Flex Direction in MudBlazor](https://mudblazor.com/utilities/flex-direction)
3. [Overflow in MudBlazor](https://mudblazor.com/utilities/overflow)

> I read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74359196/20517106) and then I wrote my solution based on it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is now in documentation:

```
<MudDialog>
    <DialogContent>
        <MudContainer Style="max-height: 300px; overflow-y: scroll">
        </MudContainer>
    </DialogContent>
</MudDialog>
```

From: https://mudblazor.com/components/dialog#scrollable-dialog